# Notification when questions/answers will be or are deleted

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, notifications, deleted-answers, auto-delete

I just realized that one of my question was deleted by Community. I can't remember being been notified about that. And since happens already at least the second time, I would be nice if SE could notify this, so that I can save my idea at least for me.

Can someone implement this?

Comment: I agree. I'd like to be notified when my answers are deleted as well. Even if I don't lose any reputation (in which case there's at least some sort of notification).

Comment: Possibly related: [Provide a way to search for a user's answers to closed questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20029)

Comment: When I do not even note my posts are deleted, what shoud I care. If it is pointed out to me, I might feel almost obliged to follow up. I am **against** a notification. (Wether the "recent deleted questiosn/answers" should be expanded is a separate matter.)

Comment: A separate remark: you say your question was deleted by Community. The rules for this are pretty clear. It is not clear why you cannot just check you questions against the criteria and save (link to) those where there is a risk.

Comment: @quid I care because I put effort in it, which is lost. With a notification I can save it. Maybe it would be good if notifications would be configurable...

Comment: No. If you want to know you should have to look it up *actively,* this minimizes noise while still allowing to retrive the content for those that actually care. Questions get deleted by Community mainly when they are neglected. Do not neglect your questions.

Comment: This behavior is implemented throughout the se system.  So to get this feature change, you will have to ask in a higher forum than math meta.

Comment: The feature got proposed on MSE, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116686/deletion-notifications) and [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/notice-of-deletion) and likely elsewhere.